# Bug when uploading app to real Apple Watch

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, watchos-6

I am trying to upload my independent watchOS App on my real Apple Watch series 5, but I am having a problem. I am receiving a issue that I telling me:

```
Unable to install "FirstTestWatch WatchKit App"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620395
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620395
Failure Reason: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001261406e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126140de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012618056a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d00bc22 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000126180301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000126008a25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d13ce8a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d13e562 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70480583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7048150e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70486ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70487452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70490a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff706db6fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff706da827 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

I am trying to figure out the problem, but I am having difficulties. The Apple Watch is with watchOS 6.1.1, MAC BOOK - macOS Catalina 10.15.2 and Xcode 11.3. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem today after getting stuck for two days.
Download [watchOSLogging.mobileconfig](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/watchOS_Logs/watchOSlogging.mobileconfig) to the paired iPhone and install it.